# Interface Builder Does Not Recognize Toolbar Buttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I created 4 UIButton's that are Custom and Plain in IB.

I added a background image to them and then placed them onto my UIToolbar.

I created IBActions and hooked up all of the buttons

I did not create @property for the buttons, but 3/4 of them appear on my toolbar when I run the app in my the simulator. **There is a blank space for the missing toolbar item, but when I click on the blank space, it calls my IBAction.**

Why isnt my 4th button appearing? If I need to declare an @property for them, will it be a UIToolbarButtonItem or a UIButton?

***Note: IB Is showing the buttons as a "Custom Button" instead of a Bar Button Item. I want a custom button because I don't want the image on the button to become inverted.***

Answer (score 2):

All that matters is that they have an `IBOutlet`, and are declared correctly for the ui element you are trying to connect to.  A `@property` isn't essential (but is good practice).  You can have the `IBOutlet` on either the declaration, the `@property`, or both.

Buttons in a toolbar are UIBarButtonItems; buttons on a plain view are UIButtons.  They are different things.  You seem confused on this issue, so please double check your code.

Comment: I setup an IBOutlet and declared the UI element as a UIButton, hooked it up in IB. Still doesn't show up.

Comment: It probably doesn't show because items on a UIToolbar have to be UIBarButtonItems.  Check the docs.

Comment: When you add a UIButton in IB, it adds a UIBarButtonItem with the UIButton as its customView.  I just checked via gdb - and I can see one normal UIBarButtonItem and 4 UIButtons on mine.

Comment: The button truly does exist, I realized the image, or the background image on the UIButton does not appear. Any thoughts?